# What is the simplest way break text into single strings to be modified and joined again using JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, push

For example, I am am working on a Pig Latin translator. I want a for loop to change the text to an array and allow the rest of my code to change single words and put it back together again as a result.

```
    var pigLatinTranslator = function(firstWord) {

      firstWord = firstWord.toLowerCase();

      var splitText = firstWord.split(' ');
      var finalResult = [];

      for (var i = 0; i < splitText.length; i++) {
        var singleWord = splitText[i];

        if (singleWord.charAt(0) !== "a" && singleWord.charAt(0) !== "e" && singleWord.charAt(0) !== "i" && singleWord.charAt(0) !== "o" && singleWord.charAt(0) !== "u") {
          var consonantsVar;
          for (var i = 0; i < singleWord.length; i++) {
          var chr = singleWord.charAt(i);

            if ((chr === 'q') && (singleWord.charAt(i + 1) === 'u')) {
             consonantsVar = (singleWord.slice(i + 2) + singleWord.slice(0, i) + "quay");
             break;

            } else if (chr === 'a' || chr === 'e' || chr === 'i' || chr === 'o' || chr === 'u') {
              consonantsVar = (singleWord.slice(i) + singleWord.slice(0, i) + "ay");
              break;
            }
          }
          return consonantsVar;
        }
          else {
          return (singleWord + "ay");
        }
      return splitText.join(' ');
      }
    };
```

Comment: `split` seems to be fine. Do you have any problems with the code, does it not work?

Comment: It will only return the first word entered as translated.

Comment: Probably because you `return` from the middle of the loop (twice). Didn't you want to assign to `finalResult[i]` or `splitText[i]` instead and then use that array?